# How to write incrementally to html template in go

Tags: go, templates, streaming

I'm building a web based data browser called Mavgo Flight.
I want large tables from sqlite to print continuously instead of the default behavior of only printing when all the data is available.  I tried running the template per row of data which fails.

```
func renderHTMLTable(w http.ResponseWriter, result *sqlx.Rows) {
    cols, err := result.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err, "renderHTMLTable")
        return
    }
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("./templates/2d.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("template failed", err)
        return
    }
    data := HTMLTable{}
    data.Cols = cols
    for result.Next() {
        cols, err := result.SliceScan()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(w, err)
            break
        }
        s := make([]string, len(cols))
        for i, v := range cols {
            s[i] = fmt.Sprint(v)
        }
        tmpl.Execute(w, s)
    }
}
```

Comment: One solution is to execute a header template, loop while executing a row template and execute a footer template.  How did executing a template for each row fail?

Comment: I attempted to just use the all-in-one template I created and just hope that template executed the part where data was available.  I ended doing exactly your thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on being clever did exactly what Cerise suggested
The function that writes rows incrementally:

```
func renderHTMLTable(w http.ResponseWriter, result *sqlx.Rows) {
cols, err := result.Columns()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err, "renderHTMLTable")
    return
}
head, err := template.ParseFiles("./templates/head.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("template failed", err)
    return
}
row, err := template.ParseFiles("./templates/row.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Println("template failed", err)
    return
}
foot := `  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>`
head.Execute(w, cols)
s := make([]string, len(cols))
for result.Next() {
    values, err := result.SliceScan()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(w, err)
        break
    }

    for i, v := range values {
        s[i] = fmt.Sprint(v)
    }
    row.Execute(w, s)
}
fmt.Fprint(w, foot)
```

}